# incomprehension with a php regex

Tags: php, regex

I have this text:

`<< /T (D3K_indicatif[0]) /V () >> << /T (D3P_pays[0]) /V () >> << /T (D1H_homme[0]) /V / >> << /T (D3K_indicatif[0]) /V () >>`

I would like to catch `<< /T (D3P_pays[0]) /V () >>`

I did this regex 
`/<< \/T\s.{0,}\(D3P_pays\[0\]\) \/V \(\) >>/gm` but this regex catch `<< /T (D3K_indicatif[0]) /V () >> << /T (D3P_pays[0]) /V () >>`

I don't understand why I have `<< /T (D3K_indicatif[0]) /V () >>` in my match.

Comment: `.` matches any char. Use `[^>]*` / `[^<>]*`  instead of `.{0,}`

Comment: Using https://regex101.com/ you will see that your quatifier `\.s{0,}` is being too greedy and hence catching `D3K_indicatif[0]` as well so change your regex to:

    << \/T\s.{0}\(D3P_pays\[0\]\) \/V \(\) >>